# What is a good book for developing an a posteriori constructed language?

Tags: language, worldbuilding-resources

I'm currently working on [an experiment using Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22688/how-long-will-it-take-to-form-a-new-dialect-and-language-in-underground-steampun?lq=1), and so I'm working on a [constructed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) to be used by some of the people in my world. I have some of the main points down, but I'm also interested in learning about the more general aspects of language-building.

What is a good book that talks about the process of creating constructed languages? Specifically, I'd like one that focuses on [*a posteriori* languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_posteriori_(languages)), because my language is in part based on (British) English.

Comment: Langages usually build themselves with time and change every time. If I were you, i would start with "recently" artificially contructed langages. I don't have a book title in mind, but i think of Tolkien elves and dwarf langages, and esperanto (it was made to give to the whole europa a single langage. It's a whole langage but nobody speaks that thing)

Answer (score 4):

Try the Verduria website. Very detailed, and comes with its own Language Construction Kit.

http://www.zompist.com/virtuver.htm
http://www.zompist.com/kit.html

A snippet for you:

*"This set of webpages (what’s a set of webpages? a webchapter?) is intended for anyone who wants to create artificial languages— for a fantasy or an alien world, as a hobby, as an interlanguage. It presents linguistically sound methods for creating naturalistic languages— which can be reversed to create non-naturalistic languages. It suggests further reading for those who want to know more, and shortcuts for those who want to know less. "*